# Obtain max length restriction from regex

Tags: regex

I was wondering if there is there a way to reliably pull the length section out of a given regular expression?  I'll give an example, say I have 100 key value pairs.  The values for each key get populated in various different ways but each value gets validated via a regular expression.  The regular expression could be anything and is never consistent, it may or may not contain a lower/upper length restriction for the value.  What I’m wondering is – is there any way to reliably pull out the max length restriction of a given expression?  The reason I need this is that if my value is too long I plan to crop it until it fits.

I am not overly familiar with regex but know enough to get by.  Correct me if im wrong but a max length always needs to be accompanied by a min length and is always in the following format:

```
{1, 30}
```

Where 1 is the min amount of characters allowed and 30 is the max.  Is it possible to do some sort of substring on the regex to look for this format and pull the number from between the ',' and '}'.  Or is there other instances where another part of the regex could look similar but mean something different?  I dont want to mistakenly pull the wrong information due to my lack of overall knowledge of regex and all the variants.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to regex a regex? As far as I understand, you habe a variety of regexes and want to extract the max length of them. Can you please post some values and the respective results? Also a length restriction can also be `{1,}` for min length of 1 or `{30}` for exact 30 characters.

Comment: Have you considered the presence of `*`, `+` and alternations? The first two make for an infinite max length, the last one makes it much harder to count a max length since you have to consider every alternation separately. Lookarounds would also make your task a bit harder (you'd need to ignore them). Quantifiers applied to groups (capturing or not) would need to see their number of occurencies multiplied by the max length of the group to obtain their max length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull those values from a string representation of a regex using a regex like so:

```
/{(\d),\s*?(\d)}/
```

You might wish to make those optional - you can have a minimum without a maximum and vice versa.

```
/{(\d)?,\s*?(\d)?}/
```

Comment: Whoops, I'll add optional whitespaces in @Aaron.

Comment: Hmm actually after checking it I think the space makes the  `{n, m}` fail to parse as a quantifier in most regex flavours ; that might just be a typo from OP, in which case you'd better not accept optional spaces. Sorry about that !